# Interactive bar chart using D3

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm trying to plot a line chart on D3, where the x-variable is a financial year like 2012-13 (instead of a standard data format). As a result, I'm considering keeping the x values as strings.

I have the following code for defining the line

```
var valueline = d3.svg.line()
    .x(function(d) { return x(d.date); })
    .y(function(d) { return y(d.close); });
```

Then, I read the data, and add the line to the chart:

```
d3.csv("data.csv", function(error, data) {
    data.forEach(function(d) {
        d.date = d.date);
        d.close = +d.close;
    });

    ...

    // Add the valueline path.
    svg.append("path")
        .attr("class", "line")
            .attr("d", valueline(data));

        ...

        // add axes etc

});
```

This isn't working and I'm getting the following error:

```
Error: <path> attribute d: Expected number, "MNaN,190.81307074…".
```

Does that mean a line chart necessarily expects a date or a number?

The data is as follows:

```
date,close
2012-13,58.13
2013-14,53.98
2014-15,67.00
2015-16,89.70
2016-17,99.00
```

Comment: You are not parsing the date probably

Comment: it would be better if you can provide the data also or create a plunker

Comment: It's not a regular date format, as I've mentioned. It's like "2012-2013", "2013-2014" and so on.

Comment: @MdJohirulIslam added the data.

Comment: look at the source of this example https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3885304

Comment: there's also another one here http://alignedleft.com/content/03-tutorials/01-d3/130-making-a-bar-chart/10.html

Answer (score 0):

The crucial bit you're not showing is how you are defining your x-scale. The line doesn't care what your data is; the scale does and since you are getting `NaN` for your x value, something is with your scale is wrong.

If you are using a time type scale (https://github.com/d3/d3-scale#scaleTime), then yes, it has to be a valid datetime, IE a unix timestamp or date object. You can use d3.timeParse (https://github.com/d3/d3-time-format#timeParse) to convert your string dates.

If you are using an ordinal type scale, such as scalePoint (https://github.com/d3/d3-scale#scalePoint), then you can use strings, but would have to pass all your date strings in for the domain:

`x.domain(data.map(function(d) { return d.date; }));`

If there are any gaps, those would also not be reflected with an ordinal type scale.